# Cannot login to ask.fedoraproject.org

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-exchange-openid

On ask.fedoraproject.org I click on Sign in, then enter the OpenID address https://openid.stackexchange.com and click on Sign in.
I am redirected to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login where I enter my username and password for stackexchange (this is the account, so credentials are okay) and after clicking Sign in, this site shows the message:

> An error occurred on the server This event has been recorded.
>
> If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it

This is for months now. On Fedora 64bit Firefox 31 and Chrome.

Comment: This is a known issue with AskBot (the Q&A software they are using) and some versions on OSQA which is what it was forked from.

Comment: Sadly, buggy OpenID clients are not uncommon. We can't really do much beyond making sure we're doing right on our end.